# node js firestore function logs error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined at exports.observeMessages.functions.database.ref.onCreate

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i am recieving this error in my firestore functions logs

TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
    at exports.observeMessages.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:23:27)

and here is my functions code

```
  exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/user-messages/{uid}/{fromId}/{messageId}')
.onCreate(event => {

var uid = event.params.uid;
var fromUid = event.params.fromId
var messageId = event.params.messageId

// let's log out some messages

console.log('User: ' + uid + 'was just messaged by: ' + fromId);



      //firestore - get users fcm token from firestore to send a push messaged


var Ref = db.collection('Users').doc(uid);
var getDoc = Ref.get()
.then(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
  return console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
   console.log('Document data:', doc.data());


   var userUID = parseFloat(doc.data().uid);

      return console.log(userUID);
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  return console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear,  `event.params` is undefined, do `console.log(event)` and show us the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Version 1.0.+ of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions but your code is using the old syntax (the one of SDK < 1.0). You can verify the version of Cloud Functions in your `package.json` file.

See this documentation item for the changes into syntax: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

You should modify your code as follows (see the first 3 lines with "Here modify"):

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/user-messages/{uid}/{fromId}/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

var uid = context.params.uid;  // <- Here modify
var fromUid = context.params.fromId  // <- Here modify
var messageId = context.params.messageId  // <- Here modify

// let's log out some messages

console.log('User: ' + uid + 'was just messaged by: ' + fromId);

      //firestore - get users fcm token from firestore to send a push messaged

var Ref = db.collection('Users').doc(uid);
return Ref.get(). // <- Here modify
.then(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
     console.log('No such document!');  // <- Here modify 
      return false;  // <- Here modify 
  } else {
   console.log('Document data:', doc.data());


   var userUID = parseFloat(doc.data().uid);

      console.log(userUID);  // <- Here modify
      //return a promise like the one returned by the sendToDevice method 
      //See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice

  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error getting document', err);  // <- Here modify, no need to return anything here
});
```

**Note that you should also modify some other part of your the code**, and not only the 3 lines at the top. As a matter of fact you need to return a promise in your Cloud Function. See the other modifications above, again with a "Here modify" comment.

I kindly (but strongly :-)) suggest that you watch these videos from the Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=28s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk which explain these key concepts.

Comment: Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?